# Constraint check on date type - not working postgresql

Tags: postgresql

While creating a table that tracks certain activity, 
I am unable to setup the date constraint to work. I get an error (shown below).

My Query:

```
create table tracker (
    event varchar(25) primary key,
    create_ydt date not null check (create_ydt > ‘2010-01-01’)   
);
```

I get the following error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3: create_ydt date not null check ()2010-01-01create_ydt >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the single quotes -- yours are curly.  Try:

```
create table tracker (
    event varchar(25) primary key,
    create_ydt date not null check (create_ydt > '2010-01-01')   
);
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/KLSOS3997) example.

Comment: This worked. Although I don't quite know in ubuntu how to type a straight vs. curly single quote.